# TFS Build and workspace

Tags: build, tfs, workspace

first, I'd like to apologize for my english, it's not my 1st language !

During a build configuration (TFS 2010), in the Workspace tab,  I can specify the needed directories in order to avoid getting the whole source code every time I run a build.

Instead of doing this, is it possible to specify to the build to automatically get the projects in the solution to build and nothing else ?

Thanks a lot for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  You have to specify a folder to get the source code from because, when you build on a server, the build step is completely separate from the get step.

This behaviour in Visual Studio is provided when you *open* a solution, and it's a feature of the IDE intended to aid developers, but if you were building direct from the commandline you'd not get this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I just found this link in which they're kind of talking about what I'm trying to do: [geekswithblogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/MartinWatts/archive/2010/04/07/stopping-your-tfs-build-server-from-getting-all-sources.aspx). What do you think about it ?  
If I understand well, it could be possible, but I have no idea what *tfsbuild project file* is in this sentence: *The solution is overriding the CoreGet task in your tfsbuild project file*.

Comment: And about the workspaces, there are few cons for me. For example: I'd like to create a build for **MyApp1**. So in the Workspace tab, I put the directory **/MyProjets/MyApp1/**, but at the end I have to put the directory **/MyProjets/** too because when the tests run, they need the **.testsettings** file located at the root. Therefore **/MyProjets/MyApp2/** and **/MyProjets/MyApp3/** are added too, and I have to cloak them because I have no interest on those files for this build. And each time I add a new project I'll have to cloak it too. I must doing something wrong, but what ?

Comment: From what you've said, your folder structure can't be used to separate your code out.  Maybe you need a deeper folder structure, or perhaps you just need to put your `.testsettings` file somewhere different.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to put the '.testsettings' file somewhere else.